# Xamarin Prism Navigation in master detail cause reload of entire page on very navigation

Tags: xamarin, prism, navigationservice

When I navigate from my master to another detail view and y return to the original pages, this is loading everything like it was the first time, is this the expected behavior or what I am doing wrong?

this is what happening

1. from my login page y navigate to my master detail page with this:

   ```
   await _navigationService.NavigateAsync("/MainMasterDetailPage/NavigationPage/PageA");
   ```
2. then from my master page I navigate to another page detail with this:

   ```
   await _navigationService.NavigateAsync(target);
   ```

where target equals `NavigationPage/PageB`

3. then I go back to my first detail pages with this:

   ```
   await _navigationService.NavigateAsync(target);
   ```

where target equals `NavigationPage/PageA`

The problem is that when PageA is showed for the second time, it was executing everything like it was the first time (Constructor for example) and I am loosing the state of the page.

How could I prevent this? it is a bug or is there a work around

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered in the Prism GitHub issue you submitted.  Please do not double post.

https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/968